# Superseach / Low search - How to handle this type of search criteria

Tags: solspace, low-search, supersearch, low

I have 2 category groups (function and material).

In my search for i have the 2 category groups listed as checkboxes, so the user can perform multiple search combinations.

How I need the search to work is, if I selected Sales and Marketing from the functions categories list and selected Videos and eBooks from the materials categories list. I want to be able to see Video and eBooks entries in either Sales or Marketing.

What is the best way for me to handle this type of query.

Comment: Should I be using `name="category[]"` for both category groups, or should they be named differently to help handle this type of thing?

Comment: So this kind of search?: (Video **AND** eBooks) **AND** (Sales **OR** Marketing)

Comment: @solspace that is correct. How best to do that with supersearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment about Super Search, but Low Search can handle this using the [Categories filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories) and its group syntax. In your case, you could use `name="category:functions[]"` for the one group, and `name="category:materials[]"` for the other.

See also the second part of the [Categories filter example here](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples#categories).

Comment: Awesome, thanks Low. I think that is the type of thing i was after

Comment: does the search only work with category_id or can category_url_title be used? Also  if i did the above, are multiple categories from each group matched in the search or will it only pull entries which are in that category. Just trying to make sure i get the above query working correct

Comment: category_id only, like the native category parameter. You can switch from *any* given category to *all* given categories using the require_all parameter LS provides.